# Diagonalizable Matrix $A$**$\in \mathcal{M_n}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Can someone please state the most known conditions for a **Matrix $A$**$\in \mathcal{M_n}(\mathbb{R})$ to be **diagonalizable**?

Without proof, just by shedding light on them please. In the means of being **symmetric**, or concerning **eigenvalues**, and so...

Comment: ${\bf R}^n$ having a basis consisting of eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: Equivalently one can define a matrix to be diagonalizable if there is an incredible matrix $S$ such that $S^{-1}AS$ is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: @Lukas, I think you mean *invertible*, not *incredible*.

Comment: All the answers state equivalent conditions. The most commonly mentioned sufficient condition for a matrix is usually the matrix being symmetric. (A related discussion can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255622/symmetric-matrix-is-always-diagonalizable?rq=1 )

Comment: @Gerry Myerson, o wow - autocorrect did a great job there. You are right, I meant to write invertible.

Answer (score 0):

If there are $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors, $$V1, V2, ..., Vn$$ then the matrix $P$ whose columns are these eigenvectors will satisfy $$ AP =PD $$ where D is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues. We may solve for A or for D depending the application on hand.  $$P^{-1}AP=D  
$$ or $$ A=PDP^{-1} $$